# Teradata - Query - Using In with equals filter

Tags: sql, filter, teradata, equals

Could someone please help me understand the difference between the below two?

```
SELECT A.ACCT_NBR 
FROM TABLE_1 A
WHERE A.ACCT_NBR IN (SELECT DISTINCT B.ACCT_NBR
                    FROM TABLE_2 B)
```

And

```
SELECT A.ACCT_NBR 
FROM TABLE_1 A
WHERE A.ACCT_NBR IN (SELECT DISTINCT B.ACCT_NBR
                    FROM TABLE_2 B
                    WHERE B.ACCT_NBR = A.ACCT_NBR)
```

Lets assume the datatypes are not an issue. 
Also I could have done a simple inner join. But I need to know details about this specific IN based queries.

The explain plan generated via SQLA are copies of each other with only differences in spool sizes (query#1 needing lesser spool size)

Sample data

```
TABLE_1
ACCT_NBR | ACCT_ID
------------------
1111     | AAAA
2222     | BBBB
3333     | CCCC
4444     | DDDD


TABLE_2
PK | ACCT_NBR | ACCT_ID
-----------------------
1  | 1111     | AAAA
2  | 3333     | CCCC
3  | 1111     | AAAA

EXPECTED RESULT
ACCT_NBR
---------
1111
3333
```

Comment: Those queries will not returm the same result. Query #1 will only succed when there's a single `ACCT_NBR` in `TABLE_2`. Query #2 is a Correlated Subquery which returns all matching rows. If this was a type and #1 is based on `IN` both are exactly the same and Explain should be the same (there might be slight variations of estimated number, but actual execution will be exactly the same). Btw, `DISTINCT` is not needed, it's automatically applied when needed, i.e. *before* the join. But when you switch to a Join you probably need to add a `DISTINCT`, which will be executed *after* the join.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for catching the typo. Yes, it was IN based. I have changed the query to replace '=' with 'IN'.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for catching the typo. Yes, it was IN based. I have changed the query to replace '=' with 'IN'. Sorry for the confusion. I tried to retype a bigger production query. I was also expecting both to be the same (when using IN). Thank you for the suggestion of the distinct clause too. jarlh, I kind of got my concern solved, still I will add some data and results for reference of others. Thank you again.